# OpenAI API error: "TypeError: OpenAIApi is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, discord, openai-api, gpt-4

I am having an issue trying to get this code to call my OPENAI_API_KEY in the `.env` file. I am very new to Node.js, so please speak to me like I'm an idiot.

See the error at the bottom after the code.

Code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

// Initialize OpenAI API client with the API key from your .env file
const openaiClient = new OpenAIApi(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY);


/**
 * Generates a response using ChatGPT-4 Turbo based on the provided user input.
 * @param {string} userInput - The user's message input.
 * @returns {Promise<string>} - The generated response from ChatGPT-4 Turbo.
 */
async function generateResponse(userInput) {
  try {
    console.log('Sending input to OpenAI API:', userInput);
    const response = await openaiClient.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-4-turbo",
      messages: [{
        role: "user",
        content: userInput
      }],
    });

    if (response.data.choices && response.data.choices.length > 0) {
      console.log('Received response from OpenAI API');
      return response.data.choices[0].message.content;
    } else {
      console.log('No response from OpenAI API.');
      throw new Error('No response from OpenAI API');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to generate response from OpenAI API:', error.message, error.stack);
    throw error; // Rethrow to handle it in the calling function
  }
}

module.exports = { generateResponse };
```

Error:

```
L:\ai projects\gpt-pilot\workspace\JS-Rock_Bot\chatService.js:5
const openaiClient = new OpenAIApi(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY);
                     ^

TypeError: OpenAIApi is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (L:\ai projects\gpt-pilot\workspace\JS-Rock_Bot\chatService.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Client.<anonymous> (L:\ai projects\gpt-pilot\workspace\JS-Rock_Bot\bot.js:34:30)
    at Client.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (L:\ai projects\gpt-pilot\workspace\JS-Rock_Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:28:14)

Node.js v20.11.1
```

I also tried this but it's not working:

```
const { OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
```

Comment: If I'm lacking in any details it's because I honestly don't know what is needed that could be helpful. I am seriously VERY NEW to all of this. I have been fighting this for almost 3 hours now trying different stuff and nothing is working.

Comment: There is no such concept of a class named `OpenAIApi` included in the most recent version of [the official `openai-node` package](https://github.com/openai/openai-node), and it's not clear where you would have gotten an idea to the contrary - can you share where you learned of this class' existence? Is this code GPT generated, and the class hallucinated, perhaps?

Comment: I am using ai to assist me and I think it might have generated that. It may be out of date. I am trying to learn this stuff as I go. After updating it to const openai = new OpenAI({ it says ReferenceError: OpenAI is not defined and has an arrow pointing to the word "new"

Comment: Further research indicates this class may have been part of the last major version release of this library; if you're willing to use an outdated version of the library then this code *may* work. However, GPT and other generative AIs are not a substitute to actually learning the language you've chosen and understanding the code it generates.

Comment: I understand, but I find I learn best when I set goals and work through problems. Ideally I'd like to use the most current syntax.

Comment: Have you read through and applied the steps outlined on the ["v3 to v4 Migration Guide" GitHub discussion on the `openai-node` repository](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217)? What happened when you did? There seems to be a method to automatically upgrade your codebase using transformers, but if your GPT-generated code mixes concepts from the v3 and v4 codebase (or other classes/components that simply don't exist) it will be significantly more effort to get this code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1: Install the most recent OpenAI Node.js SDK

You said in the comment above that you would like to use the most recent syntax. So, first of all, make sure that you have the most recent OpenAI Node.js SDK installed. Run the following command:

```
npm install openai@latest
```

As of today, `v4.29.0` is the most recent one. Before you proceed, check the version by running the following command:

```
npm view openai version
```

You should see `4.29.0` in the terminal.

### Step 2: Fix the code

You have more than one mistake in your code, but you don't know about them yet because the initialization was the first error that was thrown. After you fix this error, only then will the next error be thrown.

The OpenAI Node.js SDK >=`v4` (i.e., including the newest one) has a lot of breaking changes compared to <`v4`. Among them, it's also the initialization that caused your error. But as I said, you have more mistakes in your code.

The following is the correct **initialization** using the OpenAI Node.js SDK >=`v4`:

```
const OpenAI = require("openai");

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
```

The following is the correct **method name** using the OpenAI Node.js SDK >=`v4`:

```
openai.chat.completions.create
```

The following is the correct **message retrieval** using the OpenAI Node.js SDK >=`v4`:

```
response.choices[0].message.content
```

### Full code

```
require('dotenv').config();
const OpenAI = require("openai");

// Initialization
const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

async function generateResponse(userInput) {
  try {
    console.log('Sending input to OpenAI API:', userInput);
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({ // Method name
      model: "gpt-4-turbo",
      messages: [{
        role: "user",
        content: userInput
      }],
    });

    if (response.choices && response.choices.length > 0) {
      console.log('Received response from OpenAI API');
      return response.choices[0].message.content; // Message retrieval
    } else {
      console.log('No response from OpenAI API.');
      throw new Error('No response from OpenAI API');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to generate response from OpenAI API:', error.message, error.stack);
    throw error;
  }
}

module.exports = { generateResponse };
```